# Streaming a file in ASP.NET, C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, share

Assume we have the access to `sth.avi` on `www.dl.com` with a direct link.
e.g : `www.dl.com\sth.avi` 
Also we have a website => `www.dl2.com`.

Now, we wanna let some users to download `sth.avi` from `www.dl2.com`, but we don't have enough space on `www.dl2.com` to save `sth.avi`.
Is it possible in ASP.NET for us to read `sth.avi` from `www.dl.com` as streaming file and share it without saving the file on our domain.

P.S:
I don't wanna share this link `www.dl.com\sth.avi`, actually I wanna share something like this link `www.dl2.com\downloads\sth.avi`

Comment: Have you considered creating a virtual directory named 'download' pointing to the original file location?

Comment: Streaming server's are serious business.  You don't just drop it in with a little .net framework.  If your super limited on hard drive space/have no control over the hardware at dl.com your in even more trouble.  All in all, just by what you've said good luck.  But, start by googling for streaming server software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.... this is feasible, but it looks to me as a bad idea.

In order to achieve your result, you must open an HTTP request to `www.dl.com` (the hoster of the video) and then, once you read bytes from there, redirect them to `Response` stream.

I can't provide you with working code, but here is pseudo code

```
using (Stream fileStream = [open HTTP request to www.dl.com])
{
    while (fileStream is not ended)
    {
        buffer = fileStream.Read();
        Response.Write(buffer);
    }
}
```

I repeat: that was **pseudo-code**!!!

Comment: Maybe the one by **Justin Niessner**. Placing a redirect using Response.Redirect method

Answer (score 5):

Instead of streaming simply configure the web server on `www.dl2.com` to redirect requests for `/downloads/sth.avi` to `www.dl.com/sth.avi`.

Comment: Nice one! I was already starting to think about `WebClient` and returning a stream :)

Comment: But I can't do it for each videos or files on `www.dl.com`. I wrote just a sample.

Comment: @Mohammed - You can configure the redirects at the directory level...it doesn't need to be one per file.

Comment: @Justin - How can I configure the Server as you said? Do you have a useful link? thanks.

Comment: @Mohammad - Which Web Server are you using? That might also be a question better suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: It's not determined exactly, probably we will use some servers like RapidShare or MegaUpload or HotFile

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Make an `HttpWebRequest` to `dl.com/...` and copy the HttpWebResponse to `Response.Out`.

Make sure to disable buffering.